# C# Find the greatest number that doesn't divide by 2, 3, 5 and 7 but smaller than 1000

Tags: c#

```
  public void ListTheBiggestNumberNotDividedBy2357()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 1001; i++)
        {
            if (!(i % 2 == 0) && !(i % 2 == 0) && !(i % 5 == 0) && !(i % 7 == 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

How to display only the biggest number? I tried with Math.Max() but I guess that's not what I should write.

Comment: I would start with 1000 and descend. Then you just need to print the first one and break.

Comment: Typo? Second condition should be `!(i % 3 == 0)`

Comment: I'd also make sure your test uses the right set of integers. Yours tests for 2 twice and omits 3.

Comment: Start with 999, and increment down by 2 to 11. You already know that even numbers are excluded, so no point in even trying those ones. Break when the conditions for 3,5,7 are met.

Answer (score 6):

(Note that I have fixed your typo of `!(i % 2 == 0) && !(i % 2 == 0)`, which should be `!(i % 2 == 0) && !(i % 3 == 0)`.)

#### The slow way

Keep a `currentBiggest` and update it every time you find such a number:

```
public void ListTheBiggestNumberNotDividedBy2357()
{
    int currentBiggest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 1001; i++)
    {
        if (!(i % 2 == 0) && !(i % 3 == 0) && !(i % 5 == 0) && !(i % 7 == 0))
        {
            currentBiggest = i;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(currentBiggest);
}
```

#### The fast way

Start from 1000 and go down. Print the first number you find, and `break;`, which stops the loop.

```
public void ListTheBiggestNumberNotDividedBy2357()
{
    for (int i = 1000; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (!(i % 2 == 0) && !(i % 3 == 0) && !(i % 5 == 0) && !(i % 7 == 0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try a simple *Linq* in order to query numbers in `(1000..0]` range:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // let's extact divisors: it's easy to make a mistake like in the code in the question:
  // !(i % 2 == 0) instead of !(i % 3 == 0)
  int[] divisors = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 };

  int result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 999) // 999 - smaller than 1000
    .Reverse()
    .First(item => divisors.All(d => item % d != 0));

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  997
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a good approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = FindBiggestNumberNotDivisible(new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 }, 1000);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static int FindBiggestNumberNotDivisible(IEnumerable<int> divisibleNumbers, int maxNumber)
    {
        for (int i = maxNumber - 1; i > 0; i--)
            if (divisibleNumbers.All(x => i % x != 0))
                return i;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 997

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you can make a variable named `biggestNumber` outside of the for loop, re-write that variable in the for loop until that reaches 1000, and at the end return `biggestNumber` (and do something with that value). Not sure if that's the best way to go, but it's one way of doing it.